# Need help on Run time Error 9 Subscript out of Range

Tags: vba, excel

I was asked to fix bugs in somebody else's VBA project and unfortunately I am very new to VBA. Would appreciate if you could help me out.

So here's the macro below. I am pulling in data from 11 files into a single excel sheet but it keeps getting stuck at the 9th file. The error stated is **"Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"** When I click debug, it leads me to the line below **Workbooks(Workbookname).Sheets(Target_Worksheet).Select**

```
Private Sub MasterPull(TargetPath, Quarter, Year)

Dim Target_Worksheet As String
Target_Worksheet = "Q" & Quarter & " " & Year
Dim Target_workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Workbook As String
Source_Workbook = "Broker Captain Master.xlsm"

Dim Workbookname As String

Workbookname = Left(Mid(TargetPath, 38, 200), Len(Mid(TargetPath, 38, 200)) -5) & ".xlsx"

Set Target_workbook = Workbooks.Open(TargetPath, True, True, , "xxxxx")

Workbooks(Workbookname).Sheets(Target_Worksheet).Select

Dim HighTouchRow As Integer

HighTouchRow = WorksheetFunction.Match("High Touch (All teams)", 

Workbooks(Workbookname).Sheets(Target_Worksheet).Range("A9:A9999"), 0) + 8
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So either the workbook's name is not exactly `Workbookname`, or there is no sheet in with the name `Target_Worksheet`. If you add the line `Workbooks(Workbookname).Activate` right before that line, does the new line throw the same error?

Comment: You realize you just posted the password to that workbook, right?

Comment: @BigBen Hmm, i added that line and it still throws out the same error though

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it - you already have a workbook object from the previous line - `Set Target_workbook...` You should be using that in the next line: `Target_Workbook.Sheets(Target_Worksheet)`

Comment: @BigBen I tried that as well but it still shows the same error. Could it be that the workbook name is labelled slightly different from the rest?

    Workbookname = Left(Mid(TargetPath, 38, 200), Len(Mid(TargetPath, 38, 200)) -5) & ".xlsx"

Could you break this down for me? I think it may have to do with the file name

Comment: My point was that you don't need to use `Workbookname` at all. Once you open the file, you have a variable `Target_workbook` referencing it, so there's no need to refer to that workbook by its `Workbookname`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for helping me out, i found the source of the error. The sheet in the 9th workbook was named differently from the other 10 workbooks that was why it was stuck there. Appreciate the help still. Cheers mate